# How to verify a new email address is correct in ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfml

I have a holiday website I built years ago in ColdFusion. I'm not the best programmer so I enlisted the help of a senior programmer to do the "heavy lifting." Unfortunately, he is not available at this time.

QUESTION:
On the site, there is a form for kids to email Santa. In an effort to get them to come back, I send them a "Secret Passcode" they can use to come back to the site the next day to get Santa's response (Santa is super busy this time of year and can't respond instantly - more realistic.) I collect their email, first name and "wish list" info and stuff it into a DB.

The problem I'm having is that a reasonable percentage of kids/parents mistype their email address (e.g. suzy@gmial.com vs suzy@gmail.com) causing them to never get their "Secret Passcode" or hear back from the North Pole at all! This, of course, could be challenging for Santa believers wondering why Santa never got back to them.

Is there a way to do a real time check to see if the email address is valid BEFORE entering it into the DB, and toss up a response page stating "The email address you entered is not valid. Please check that you spelled it correctly" or something similar.

~ North Pole Needs Your Help.

Comment: Usually you can provide an email verification procedure, send an email to the addresses and let kids to click "confirm" button in the email.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like that will have to be the route to take.

Comment: Is there any canned code I can use for this?

Comment: I posted a jQuery plugin that offers what you are requesting.  (Confirming the emails is important, but they'll never receive the initial email if they enter it incorrectly.)

Comment: @MJRoz What did you end up doing?  Did you add a confirmed opt-in step (highly recommended anyway)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using mailcheck?  It's a Javascript library and jQuery plugin that suggests a right domain when your users misspell it in an email address.  The developers of the script claim it has reduced their sign up confirmation email bounces by 50%.  There are instructions available for jQuery & non-jQuery usage.

https://github.com/mailcheck/mailcheck

Check out the live demo here (and enter "suzy@gmial.com").

http://kicksend.com/join

You'll need to perform server-side validation using ColdFusion before you use CFMail or the user will get a visible error. Use `isvalid("email", Form.Email)` to determine if the address is valid.

Answer (score 0):

And now it's up to me to disappoint Santa? Oh, my...

It is not possible.

You cannot check for typos. Example? Your example: gmial.com is valid.

You can do a rough check `one of more characters followed by an @ sign followed by two or more characters followed by a dot followed by two or more characters` There are a lot of regular expression to be found online, just ask Google for "regular expression email javascript". Please choose a simple one.

The only thing is hoping that the email-sending process is fast and add a line or two to ask them to check their email and if there is nothing in it in a minute or two they have to check if their email is correct. You may have the password-input on the same page they send you their data, to raise the chance they keep that page open.

Comment: Didn't think so, but I greatly appreciate your response.

Comment: I know you don't like it but we cannot change the fact that thee is no way to get e receipt for an email, there is no such thing as a certified email. if you need one you can use other messaging systems like WhatsApp (but you can switch it off now, if I remember it correctly). So it's only coals in my stockings this x-mas? ;-)

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure it was possible (in fact, I didn't think it was,) but I'm a firm believer that if you don't ask, the answer is always no. I may look at the suggestion "rhgb" gave me by trying to implement the standard "re-enter your email" verification process and compare the two to see if they match. Do you know if there is any canned code for that? (FYI: I checked the Naughty & Nice List… currently you're still listed as Nice!  ;)

Comment: I don't know about something for email but there is a lot out there for password verification (The two inputs with "type password here", "retype password" you know from every website) and reuse it, The single difference is in the HTML not in the JavaScript. Here is one for example: http://keithscode.com/tutorials/javascript/3-a-simple-javascript-password-validator.html

Comment: I'll give it a shot! Thanks much. Have a Happy Holiday season!